# How to resize the modal width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have created an image gallery using a bootstrap modal window. But all my images are coming in small size. how to adjust the modal size according to the width of the image. Please any one help me doing this.

Comment: Adding some code to your question helps making it more appealing and conform to StackOverflow standards. Secondly, please tell what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I 100% understand your question without seeing any code, but why would you change the modal size depending on the image?

Have you tried setting the width of the images to 100% in your CSS?